# Spring boot configuration issues with sonar

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

'ABCService' is not reachable by @ComponentsScan or @SpringBootApplication. Either move it to a package configured in @ComponentsScan or update your @ComponentsScan configuration.

This the error message I get in 9 critical bugs in Sonarqube analysis, one for each Service and Controller.

Though @Autowire and dependency injection is working fine but still Sonar seems to be complaining.

The rule in question causing the issue is:

[Spring beans should be considered by "@ComponentScan"](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4605)

> Spring beans belonging to packages that are not included in a
>   @ComponentScan configuration will not be accessible in the Spring
>   Application Context. Therefore, it's likely to be a configuration
>   mistake that will be detected by this rule. Note: the @ComponentScan
>   is implicit in the @SpringBootApplication annotation, case in which
>   Spring Boot will auto scan for components in the package containing
>   the Spring Boot main class and its sub-packages.

Since @SpringBootApplication is has component scan which scans main class package and all it's sub packages as well this issue shouldn't come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a SonarQube bug, it doesn't handle SpringBootApplication properly. You should report it here : https://community.sonarsource.com/c/bug

Answer (score 1):

To quote from Rules from Sonar,

> @ComponentScan is used to determine which Spring Beans are available
>   in the application context. The packages to scan can be configured
>   thanks to the basePackageClasses or basePackages (or its alias value)
>   parameters. If neither parameter is configured, @ComponentScan will
>   consider only the package of the class annotated with it. When
>   @ComponentScan is used on a class belonging to the default package,
>   the entire classpath will be scanned.
>
> This will slow-down the start-up of the application and it is likely
>   the application will fail to start with an
>   BeanDefinitionStoreException because you ended up scanning the Spring
>   Framework package itself.

Find below the link and tehy have also mentioned how to write compliant code.

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4602

Comment: I've added the rule causing the issue in the update.

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4605